# JasperReport Java two tables one by one in one report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I was looking for a possibility to display two tables in one report. The point is that second one have to be displayed after whole first one. I was trying to put one under the second in Detail_1 part, but it is not working(only one row of first one is being displayed).How to configure them in ireport to get such an effect?
Thank you in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that they probably 'orverwrite' each other. Best way to fix this is as follows (I use JasperSoft Studio, which is the follow up of iReport and works great):

- In your Project Outline (don't know what it's called in iReport); the panel in which 'Detail_1' part is visible as well as the Title, Styles etc. Right-click on 'Detail_1' and then click 'Add band'. This way you add a new band, which does it's own sizing.
- Move youre second table to Detail_2 and you're done.

Hope it helps